# QNetworkAccessManager - finished signal never triggers the slot

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I'm trying to use `QNetworkAcessManager` to get the source of a url ..
But it seems that there's a problem with the signal-slot complex!

my `onFinished(QNetworkReply*)` is never triggered!  Why?

```
void Worker::start(QString url)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Worker::onFinished(QNetWorkReply * reply)
{
    qDebug() << "Slot has been triggered!";

    QString html = reply->readAll();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As "Oleg Shparber" stated, here's my new code ( which also doesn't work ):

```
void Worker::start(QString url)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinished()));


void Worker::onFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Slot has been triggered!";

    QString html = reply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: I have changed my answer accordingly to your question update.

Comment: @OlegShparber Thank you so much .. I was going to notify you that it was a minor mistake :)

Comment: Been a while since you posted this.  But are you sure your Worker object itself hadn't been deleted before the request can get to it?  *(That's what happened to me... a stack allocated object submitting the request and expecting to get a response, but it was gone by the time the request came back...)*  FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Your [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) is destructed immediately after control reaches the end of the `start()` method (See [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for details.). You need to create `QNetworkAccessManager` dynamically and keep it alive while request is performing.

Also, you are connecting to nonexistent signal. There is [QNetworkReply::finished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#finished), but no `QNetworkReply::finished(QNetworkReply*)`. You can also use [QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply*)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) if you need a pointer to [QNetworkReply](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html).

Comment: Even when I used `QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onFinished()));` and changed my slot's prototype to `void Worker::onFinished()` nothing happens also. Why?

Comment: Thanks you for helping me budd :) ... I've created `QNetworkAccessManager` dynamically, changed my slot, but nothing seems to work :(